# CSS div element make bigger hover area

Tags: css

I have an div element width 100px and height 100px. And inside of it i have another element width 100px and height 80px with border which I make disappear on hover but i need it to disappear on hover at the parent element, so also on the 20px below. I hope my question is clear ^^

Parent div:

```
.whilelist
{   
    display: block;     
    float: right;
    width: 226px;
    height: 210px;  
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: white; 
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.whilelist:hover
{           
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;  
}
```

And inside:

```
.whilebilder
{           
    width: 220px;
    height: 180px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px; 
}

.whilebilder:hover
{           
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: white;    
}
```

Comment: Your question would be a lot more clear if it had your attempts or code..

Comment: post your html and css code

Comment: _"I hope my question is clear"_. I was hoping for that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the action in the `parent:hover`. Some like:

```
.whilelist:hover .whilebilder { 
  display: none;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/ghpDb/3/**

Comment: disappear = same color as the background which makes it invisible. I tried your code its not working

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it with JQuery.

```
$('.class1').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#text-wrapper').hide();
});
$('.class1').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#text-wrapper').show();
});
```